# In flutter web html version widget to image or screenshot is not working properly [Flutter 3] [ClipPath]

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, html2canvas

Flutter has a way to convert any widget to an image by  `boundary?.toImage()`. But it doesn't work on the flutter web HTML version. So I am using a JS library [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to take snapshots of widget.
This is the js function used on the native side.

```
async function captureImageHtmlCanvas(x, y, width, height, scale) {
  // Get The canvas

  try {
    var canvas = await html2canvas(document.body, {
      x: x,
      y: y,

      width: width,
      height: height,
      scale: scale || 1
    });

    return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg", 1);
  } catch (e) {
    return reject(e);
  }
}
```

It was working in **flutter 2**, But after **flutter 3.0** updated it's not working anymore, Flutter's custom **ClipPath is getting avoided** if child has any **image**.

```
<img src="https://github.com/shofizone/widget_to_image_flutter_web_html/blob/master/Screenshot%202022-12-01%20at%208.52.13%20AM.png?raw=true" alt="drawing" width="300"/>
```

here is full code  in git [repository](https://github.com/shofizone/widget_to_image_flutter_web_html).
`https://github.com/shofizone/widget_to_image_flutter_web_html`

1. Clone the repo
2. Run `flutter run -d Chrome --web-renderer html`
3. Try to capture an image with save FAB.

**Expected results:** Expected result Image should be captured as it looks on the UI. It should be available on the bottom of the heart shape.

**Actual results:** Image gets captured properly but the custom shape is missing in the captured image.

I didn't find any other way to make it work in HTML version. While I don't want to use the canvasKit version because it is heavy in size and the web app becomes slow when it loads too many images. This issue is breaking out on the production site.